# Command does not return results in SWIFT

Tags: shell, redirect, terminal, command, nstask

I'm trying to run a command line tool and taking the result.
I checked it in terminal:

```
/usr/bin/exiftool -filename -directory -createdate -model "/Users/dirk/Desktop\" -t -S -q -r -f >"RenamerOutfile0.txt"
```

This runs fine and delivers result in file.
Using SWIFT I tried this:

```
let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/exiftool"
task.arguments = ["-filename -directory -createdate -model \"/Users/dirk/Desktop\" -t -S -q -r -f"]
let pipe = NSPipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.launch()

let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
```

Unfortunatly nothing happens. data is assigned 0 byte - no result.
If I insert the redirection to file no file is created.
Any idea what's the difference in calling the tool from terminal than with this task?

Comment: use: `["-filename", "-directory", "-createdate" ...]` e.g. array of args. also you probably want convert the data to plain String.

Comment: I added:<code>
task.arguments = ["-filename", "-directory", "-createdate", "-model", "\"/Users/dirk/Desktop\"", "-t", "-S", "-q", "-r", "-f"]<code>
later on I want to use
let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!.stringByAppendingString("")
but data is still 0 bytes long.

Comment: Couldn't format my text, because I was too slow! :-) 5 min limit

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
let x = system("/usr/bin/exiftool -filename -directory -createdate -model \"/Users/dirk/Desktop\" -t -S -q -r -f >\"/var/tmp/RenamerOutfile0.txt\"")
```

This works fine. Maybe because I added the path /var/tmp for output file? Doesn't matter! :-)